# How do I animate the position of a shape?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

How do I change the code to allow an ellipse to move instead of an image?

I know I have to use Graphics2D class...
and I think I gotta add Ellipse into Panel..
like

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapeArray = new ArrayList<Shape>();
public MyPanel(){
Shape s;
s= new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 80, 50);
shapeArray.add(s);
```

How could I make this work?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private final int WIDTH = 500;
    private final int HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int START_X = 0;
    private final int START_Y = 250;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x, y;
    
    public MyPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        File input = new File("starship.png");
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        x = START_X;
        y = START_Y;
        timer = new Timer(20, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x+=1;
        y-=1;
        if(x>WIDTH) {
            x=START_X;
            y=START_Y;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        add(new MyPanel());
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for Graphics2D.drawOval()?

Comment: Or you could also make use of the Ellipse class, and Graphics2d.draw(shape)